# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.areef.pamur.Model.ClothingCategory

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.areef.pamur.Model.ClothingCategory

com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.areef.pamur.Model.ClothingCategory

package com.areef.pamur.EndUser;
public class ClothingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private DatabaseReference ClothingRef;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private String type = "";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_clothing);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    ClothingRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Category").child("Clothing");

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.clothing_category_list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ClothingCategory> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ClothingCategory>()
                    .setQuery(ClothingRef.orderByChild("name"), ClothingCategory.class).build();


    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ClothingCategory, ClothingCategoryViewHolder> adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ClothingCategory, ClothingCategoryViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ClothingCategoryViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final ClothingCategory model) {


                    holder.txtClothingCategorytName.setText(model.getName());
                    Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.clothingCategoryImageView);


                    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            if (type.equals("Admin")) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ClothingActivity.this, AdminMaintainProductsActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("pid", model.getPid());
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else if (model.getName().equals("Men")) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ClothingActivity.this, ClothingActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("name", model.getName());
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else if (model.getName().equals("Women")) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ClothingActivity.this, ElectronicsActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("name", model.getName());
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else if (model.getName().equals("Kids")) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ClothingActivity.this, FoodActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("name", model.getName());
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }


                        }
                    });
                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public ClothingCategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_clothing_items_layout, parent, false);
                    ClothingCategoryViewHolder holder = new ClothingCategoryViewHolder(view);
                    return holder;
                }
            };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();


}
```

}

1. [View Holder Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXQ2Z.png)
2. [Model Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObX4Q.png)
3. [Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wurRn.png)

Comment: you should write what you are trying to do and how you got this error. Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not provided the action that resulted in this exception, I cannot say much other than to refer the documentation of Firebase to figure out your exception.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseException

But from what I saw, there is an issue in your code.

1. the variable `type` is left as an empty string after your declaration, therefore the conditional statements you placed inside the `onBindViewHolder()` against the `type` would not generate an output for `Admin`
2. The issue is most likely caused because of your firebase structure and the way you are trying to retrieve your data. You have childs under `Clothing` as `Kids` & `Men` and in the database reference -

   ClothingRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Category").child("Clothing"); you are not accessing any of the childs within `Clothing`. Therefore you are accessing an invalid data set.

My suggestion would be to create a model class for `Kids` and modify your query statement as   `ClothingRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Category").child("Clothing").child("Kids);` and see what your output would be.

For any additional information, refer to the official FirebaseUI documentation for the Realtime Database - https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/database/readme/

Comment: As a Admin has a privilege to add new Categories like Clothing, Electronics, Food etc and also add sub Categories like Men, Women, and Kids. Have created only one Model class for all Categories like Clothing, Electronics, Food didn't create model class for each Category. That was worked without an error, but sub Categories like Men Women kids not working

Comment: Could you please join Team Viewer to solve my issue

Comment: You could sort clothing via types and generate queries based on that.

Comment: Yes i can join and help you.

Comment: Are you available now to join

Comment: I'm from India   
+91 7013838344 its my what's app number

Comment: Why don't you start by having like an inheritance hierarchy for your Categories. And then you could have a main home activity that shows the categories available and upon click of each category, a fragment is inflated with a query set to retrieve data from each category

Comment: I'm doing same as you said, reading data from child was not working

Comment: I'm getting error as com.google.firebase.database.databaseexception: can't convert object of type java.lang.string to type com.areef.pamur.model.clothing

Comment: ClothingRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Category").child("Clothing").child("Kids");

Comment: Did you try the solution i told you?

Comment: Give me your what's app number so that I can contact you